# Invoking a management.azure.com REST API will create an entry in Log Analytics?

Tags: azure-log-analytics

If we invoke any REST API like : GET [https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/{name}?api-version=2019-08-01](https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/%7BsubscriptionId%7D/resourceGroups/%7BresourceGroupName%7D/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/%7Bname%7D?api-version=2019-08-01)
for a particular resource, does an entry gets created in associated Log Analytics Workspace?

Comment: With the existing functionality in place, you can send activity logs to Log Analytics workspace, by enabling the diagnostic settings. Once this is configured successfully you should be able to see the activity logs in Log Analytics Workspace. 
https://i.imgur.com/fQ8SzdC.png

Comment: However based on the initial investigations, the web api GET calls (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/appservice/web-apps/get)  are not getting recorded in the activity logs, so we cannot further review the same logs in Log Analytics workspace. We are further checking internally with our team to confirm the same, will keep you posted as we hear more information.

Answer (score 0):

Azure activity logs contains all write operations (PUT, POST, DELETE) for your resources. However it doesn't include read operations (GET).Please refer to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/view-activity-logs) documentation for additional information.

Based on above information we can confirm that invoking a REST API GET call will not create any entry in Activity logs or Log Analytics.

Hope the information helps, please revert back if you have any further queries.